# Традиционные (не com-dll) dll файлы написанные на visual prolog не загружаются в visual studio c++ , clion с настройками msvc и mingw

Tags: c++, qt, delphi, visual-c++, mingw

Файл.def в проект включаю.
Из visual prolog в visual prolog все работает.
Из visual prolog в rad studio c++ все работает.
Из rad studio c++ в visual prolog все работает.
Из rad studio delphi в visual prolog ? в обе стороны все работает даже без файл.def.

В visual studio c++

```cpp
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
HMODULE dll = LoadLibraryW(L"C:/prolog/res/Exe64/res.dll");
if (!dll) {
    cout << "dll не загружена";
    system("pause");
}
    
FARPROC farproc = GetProcAddress(dll,"exp");
if (!farproc) {
    cout << "нет функции";
    system("pause");
}
```

В visual studio c++ пишет "dll не загружена".

И еще сталкивался , местные qt-шные dll из qt в qt работают, если в qt в проекте подключаются как-бы общедоступные заголовочные файлы к примеру iostream тогда c msvc , mingw dll , visual prolog работают , как только подключаю файл к примеру String.h как-бы может он считается собственностью qt в qt , все dll с msvc , mingw , Visual Prolog dll не работают , тогда  надо в qt убрать #include<String.h> , очистить проект потом dll с  msvc , mingw , Visual Prolog все работает.

С чем это связано и как с этим бороться?

Comment: *"Файл.def в проект включаю."* - ¿Но зачем? После неудачного вызова необходимо вызывать `GetLastError` для уточнения ошибки. Ну и такое ощущение, что вы пытаетесь грузить dll, не озаботившись подгрузкой дерева ее зависимостей.

Comment: Проверьте разрядность (x64 / x86 ... ).

Comment: GetLastError , ошибка № 126

Comment: C:\prolog\res\Exe64\res.dll:
        Verified:       Unsigned
        Link date:      0:03 12.09.2023
        Publisher:      n/a
        Company:        n/a
        Description:    n/a
        Product:        res
        Prod version:   0.0.0.0
        File version:   0.0.0.0
        MachineType:    64-bit

C:\prolog\res\Exe64>